# How get few values from a bag with Pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have file like this:

```
cat > hdfs_bag.txt
{(1,pawel,kowalski,36),(4,pawel,kowalski,47)}
{(2,john,smith,55),(5,john,smith,66)}
{(3,paul,psmithski,44),(6,paul,psmithski,88)}
```

and I load it converting it into a bag:

```
grunt> a = load 'hdfs_bag.txt' as (b1 : bag { k1:tuple (id, name, surname, age)});
grunt> describe a;
a: {b1: {k1: (id: bytearray,name: bytearray,surname: bytearray,age: bytearray)}}
```

The result I'd like to achieve is bag with two tuples containing id and age only:

```
({(1,36),(4,47)})
({(2,55),(5,66)})
({(3,44),(6,88)})
```

Can you at least suggest first steps?

Regards 
Pawel

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution:

```
 b = foreach a generate $0.($0,$3);
```

gives result as expected:

```
({(1,36),(4,47)})
({(2,55),(5,66)})
({(3,44),(6,88)})
```

So easy, but not so obvious...

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the earlier suggested solution, instead of positional notation have gone for accessing the fields using alias ( ref : http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/basic.html#relations)

```
 A = LOAD 'hdfs_bag.txt' USING  PigStorage('\t') AS (b1 : bag { k1:tuple (id:int, name:chararray, surname:chararray, age:int)});

 B = FOREACH A GENERATE b1.(id,age);
```

**Output :**

```
 ({(1,36),(4,47)})
 ({(2,55),(5,66)})
 ({(3,44),(6,88)})
```

Answer (score 0):

After loading data in `a` clias then you can use following,

```
b = foreach a generate b1.(id,age);
dump b;
```

The advantage of this code when compared to your code (which involves $0,$3) is that, it is more readable & understandable.